# catalog search page not working magento 2

Tags: search, magento2

Hi when i search on my magento 2 site if product didn't exists its working fine and showing this message

> Your search returned no results.

but when the product exists in system its showing page like this[image]

can any one please tell me whats the issue with this i have already checked exception and log files nothing is there

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution my theme was creating this issue in this file

> app/design/frontend/Meigee/versatile/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/filter.phtml

hope it may helpful for others as well.

Comment: Please report it to the theme authors too, that would be more useful for theme and it's users.